# vertical-align with length value doesn't work on iOS 8

Tags: ios, css, mobile-safari

Apparently, `vertical-align` with length or percentage value stopped working with iOS 8 (the current latest version – 8.0.2). The interesting thing is that it's still working on <= iPhone 5, but broken on newer devices.

An isolated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6m401xwg/embedded/result/

Is this a known issue? Any workarounds without resorting to other CSS property?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found a solution to this bug: make the vertical-aligned element `display: inline-block`. It doesn't work for `display: inline` elements.

See updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6m401xwg/2/embedded/result/

Comment: I have noticed this this seems to be true only for iOS 8 iPads. On my iPhone, it works. Can you confirm or argue this?

Comment: I found that regardless of ipad vs iphone, it seems to be a bug with v8.0.x but is fixed in v8.1.x